# Make laravel schedule command last day of month at time

Tags: laravel

I'm trying to run a command the last day of the month at 06:00, I tried doing this

```
$schedule->command('crawl')->when(function () {
return \Carbon\Carbon::now()->endOfMonth()->isToday();
})->at('06:00');
```

It does run on the last day, but the "at" does not work. Any idea how I can get it to work?

Comment: Does it not run at all? Does it run on another specific time?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'd simply use the `monthlyOn()` schedule method, because it gives you the opportunity to point at a given day of the month and a daytime to execute the command. Using php's `date()` function to retrieve the count of days in a month, this becomes an enjoyable task:

```
->monthlyOn(date('t'), '6:00');
```

Comment: Awesome, this seems like the simple way :)

Comment: $schedule->command('calculateWarehouseStockValue:run')
            ->monthlyOn(date('t'), '23:50')
            ->withoutOverlapping();

DID same but not work in case of FEB any idea why???

Answer (score 2):

You can run this; dailyAt instead of <del>at</del> function

```
$schedule->command('crawl')->dailyAt('06:00')->when(function () {
    return \Carbon\Carbon::parse('last day of last month')->isToday();
});
```

Comment: I guess you meant `('last day of this month')`. Since the code you provided checks if today is last day of past month.

Answer (score 1):

If you use Laravel version 7+  then you can use **lastDayOfMonth** inbuild method

```
$schedule->command('crawl')->lastDayOfMonth('06:00');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
->lastDayOfMonth('18:00');
```

You may want to specify timezone, like this

```
->lastDayOfMonth('18:00')->timezone('Africa/Lagos');
```